# PHP json_encode produces quoted json but JS expects it to be without quotes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, json

What I need:

```
[
     {label:'Hotel'},
     {label:'Event Regristration'},
     {label:'Airfare'}
]
```

what is generated by my code

```
[
     {'label':'Hotel'},
     {'label':'Event Regristration'},
     {'label':'Airfare'}
]
```

with

```
$series[]['label'] = "some value";
```

Is there a difference between the to json examples? Actually the first one is working with jqPlot and the second one not. Any ideas how can remove the quotes? Other suggestions?

Comment: Both representations are identical and should work. I would say there's some problem with how jqPlot uses the input string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON uses double quotes instead of single to delimit strings, so what you show is technically not JSON (altough it looks similar, and it will work as a JavaScript object literal).

Fixing your code to emit double quotes should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a difference between the to json examples?

Neither is JSON.

There is no difference between the JS literal syntaxes though.

> Actually the first one is working with jqPlot and the second one not

That seems unlikely… define "not working". What errors do you get? What behaviour do you get.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly with javascript.

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/kQ3pH/